# Mac Mouse Coordinates != Window Frame?

Tags: macos, mouse, desktop, coordinates, multiple-monitors

Here's my issue.  Hopefully I can explain it well enough.  My desktop is a 2x2 with monitors of size (2048,1152).

I'm trying to use an ancillary device to generate mouse clicks.  My mouse click is supposed to be on coordinate (1600,1407)-ish (on the "pan button"), assuming (0,0) is the top-left of my entire desktop area.  It moves the mouse to the correct position, but when I perform a `CGREctContainsPoint()`) it gives me `NO` as a result.

The rectangle(frame) given by my pop-up window has origin of (1558,-406)?  So the math is correct for `CGREctContainsPoint()`, but the window's frame *should* contain the point.  (even more so as I can *see* the mouse cursor over the window.)

Why?  Is it because it is a child window? (center of my desktop is in center of the image, each window is a different background color.)
[image: center of my desktop is in center of the image, each window is a different background color.]

I have tried using the following:

```
NSRect pFrame = [_popupWindow frame];
NSPoint pOrigin = pFrame.origin;
NSPoint correctedOrigin = [[_popupWindow parentWindow] convertBaseToScreen:pOrigin];
pFrame.origin = correctedOrigin;
```

but that gives me:

`... Rect {{1488, -1529}, {439, 306}}, Point {1556.17, 1314.76}, InRect 0`

as a result, which still doesn't place the point (which I can see hovering over the pop-up window) in the rect.

Why is the rect for my popup window and the point not even remotely the same?  How can I get them in the same coordinate "space"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a mac, (0,0) is in the bottom-left corner. How are you getting the mouse coordinates? The window's frame will be in screen coordinates, so if the point is in it's base coordinates you need to call `point = [window convertBaseToScreen:point];` before comparing.

Here are two ways to get the mouse location in cocoa:

```
NSPoint location = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
//already in screen coordinates, no need to convert
```

or

```
//window is a variable containing your window
NSPoint location = [window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
//convert to screen coordinates
location = [window convertBaseToScreen:location];
```

Comment: are you sure it's the bottom-left?  If I create a `CGEventRef m = CGEventCreateMousEvent()` and I pass it a coordinate where y > screen height it shows up in the bottom-left screen.

Comment: It depends on what system you are using. Carbon (which you are using to get the location) uses the top as 0, while Cocoa (which you are using to get your window location) uses the bottom as 0. I will edit my post to show how to get the mouse from Cocoa.